# setTheme. The theme is not applied until activity is fully loaded

Tags: android, themes

I am using setTheme to change Activity theme based on user preferences. The problem is that if activity takes some time to load I see the original theme specified in AndroidManifest.xml

For example, with code given below I'll see original theme for 2 seconds, and only then it will be switched to MyTheme

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Is there any workaround to apply MyTheme immediatelly?

Comment: hi alex,try to apply theme on `onContentChanged()` because this method is called before `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`